# Managing TFS Items outside of VS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015, tfvc

I recently started to work on a fairly large project that is based on HTML and Angular 5. Several people/contractors will be working on this code and will be using different tools. For example, I like to use VS Code, while our contractor loves WebStorm.

My Company uses TFS 2015 to store and manage source code. All of my other project use VS 2017 as the editor, and VS has stuff "built in" that handle source get/push just great, keeps track of pending files, etc.

VS Code DOES have a TFS plugin, however as I learned yesterday, it only works for "local workspaces" and does not work for "server workspaces" which is what we have setup and require.

When I open the working folder in VS 2017 and look at the source control tab, it shows me all the "changed" files just fine, but any "new" files are completely ignored. They don't even show up in the right hand side of the source control screen that is supposed to be showing me the local files. It only shows me local files that also exist in TFS, not those that don't.

My question is, I need some way to manage my files and get them pushed up to TFS, both changed and new files. Is there a command line option that would do this? Or is there a way to tell VS 2017 to show me "new" files as well as changed so I can add them to the pending files?

How do you manage files via TFS when not using VS 2017, or how do you get VS 2017 to play nicely with environments outside of itself?

I hope my question makes sense. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by jessehouwing's answer below? any update?

Comment: No. I did add VSTE but to be honest, I'm not even sure what that did, as I don't see it in my programs list. I run VS Pro 2017 and just add files by hand as he mentions below, but that's not a good solution, and requires me to run a Compare to add files since the source code explorer doesn't show local files that aren't already part of the solution. Changing our setup to GIt or local is not an option for business reasons, so...

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install [Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) from the Visual Studio page. That's a good starting point. That will also install `tf.exe` which enables you to do most things from the commandline in Windows.

You can install the cross-platform version of tf alongside [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere). That also hooks into Eclipse.

For the IntelliJ family (phpStorm, webStorm, pyStorm etc...) there is a [VSTS plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services) that will work with TFS as well.

With Server workspaces you have to explicitly add and delete files through the UI or the commandline and there is no auto-detection. It's why it's highly recommended to switch to local workspaces. It's the default since 2015 and it does offer a better 'feeling' for people who are used to Git of SVN.

Also, remember that Team Foundation Server 2015 and later supports Git repositories, which are really the way forward if you'd ask me. It has a richer experience in the Web, much easier cross platform use and is supported in just about every IDE out there. TFVC, while supported and with a bunch of options ou there, they just feel less polished.